# Sql Server 2012 error 8120. group by error on a simple select query

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my table creation code

```
      CREATE TABLE "transactions" (
    "id" INT NOT NULL,
    "tno" INT NOT NULL,
    "pno" INT NOT NULL,
    "sno" INT NOT NULL,
    "accode" INT NOT NULL,
    "acname" VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    "date" DATE NOT NULL,
    "truck" VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    "weight" DECIMAL NULL,
    "quality" INT NULL,
    "debit" MONEY NOT NULL,
    "credit" MONEY NOT NULL,
    "amount" MONEY NOT NULL,
    "comment" TEXT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
```

I want to get some data from this table by this query.

```
 Select * from  transactions GROUP BY tno
```

but it gives me error:

```
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'transactions.tno' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

finaly i got solution . my answer is

```
   select yt.id, yt.tno, yt.accode, yt.acname, yt.pno, yt.comment, yt.amount, yt.date from transactions yt inner join( select tno, max(id) id from transactions ss group by tno ) ss on yt.id = ss.id and yt.tno = ss.tno order by yt.tno desc
```

Comment: i tried that but not working for me thats why i post here.

Comment: Google search *"How to use group by"*. Please describe what you are after, no point using `groupby` if you going to `select *`

Comment: @huMpty duMpty i actuly want to get data of distinct value of tno with all the columns

Comment: i am new to sql so i need help. i dnt know why people not welcome begineers.

Comment: @user3631434 grouping would mean combining rows together to show totals or min/max values. so you can't have all of the rows and have them grouped. Are you looking to order by, rather than group, so that all tno's are together?

Comment: @user3631434 We do welcome beginners. But beginners want to learn, rather than just copy and paste code until it works.

Comment: @Tanner i need distinct with tno. and all columns with selected tno

Comment: @user3631434 if you want some help I suggest you add some dummy data to this SQL Fiddle I have set up for you: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fb13c/1 and then update the question to show what you would like the output to look like based on the updated fiddle

Comment: @user3631434 if you do what I suggested, I will happily help you. if you continue to ask the same question without giving it proper context then I can't help you.

Comment: @Tanner check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2ca30/3 it just select one column tno. but i want the complete row of the selected tno. i hope now you can understand

Comment: sorry, that' not enough for me to answer, make a few rows with something near to real data and edit the question with what you would like to see as your output. perhaps reduce the number of columns so it's easier to look at.

Comment: @Tanner if i want select all like this query http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2ca30/4 then it start distinct every column

Comment: please do as requested and i'll take a look

Comment: @Tanner this is what i was looking for.     select yt.id, yt.tno, yt.accode, yt.acname, yt.pno, yt.comment, yt.amount, yt.date
from transactions yt
inner join(
    select tno, max(id) id
    from transactions ss
    group by tno 
) ss on yt.id = ss.id and yt.tno = ss.tno order by yt.tno desc

Answer (score 1):

GROUP BY allows you to collect data about mathematical operations and collect them under non-mathematical ones.

For example

```
SELECT truck, SUM(tno)
FROM transactions
GROUP BY truck
```

Would give you the total values of TNO field for each type of "truck" you have in your table. The mathematical operator here is SUM.

So if your table contained this:

```
truck   tno
------------
dodge    44
viper    33
dodge    22
```

The above query would return

```
truck   tno
------------
dodge    66
viper    33
```

You're using GROUP BY without a math operator, so the query fails. To just get your data use

```
 Select * from  transactions
```

Or if you do want to use a math operator to get some data, tell us more clearly what you're trying to achieve rather than just posting table structure and a failing query.

Comment: i need all the columns in result. but with your query it show error on more then 2 columns.

Comment: You're still not telling us what you want. If you just want all your data, use the query at the bottom - Select * from  transactions - but if you want an actual group by, tell us what math operator you're using on what column and what the groups you need are. Alternative, take the advice in the comments and actually *read about* and *understand* the language you're trying to use. My example is supposed to help demonstrate to you *how* basic sql queries work. Take the time to think about it, rather than rushing to copy code.

Comment: i want all columns with distinct of tno

Comment: Select distinct(tno),pno,date,accode,acname,truck, weight, quality, amount from transactions       i use this query but it distinct all the columns written above. i jst want to distinct tno

Comment: EDIT - oh, I see. Try SELECT DISTINCT tno FROM transactions

Comment: it only return tno column

Comment: @MattThrower A+ for effort, but please give up and do something useful :-)

Comment: Yes, it will, because you asked for "just distinct tno", which is what I gave you. Sorry, I give up. I suggest you do some more reading on basic SQL so you can at least ask your questions in a meaningful manner. Try http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp

Comment: @Tanner Yes. I'm pretty new to actually trying to answer questions rather than just ask them. Learning the hard way that it's rarely worthwhile :)

Comment: @MattThrower it distict tno but how to get other columns with this query? i want all record of that selected tno row

Comment: @MattThrower you can help me. you are very near to result. i was just stuck on this topic from morning. by searching and searching. tired of searching and then post question here. please complete this.